# What to do instead of nested fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've read here: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments that "Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a . Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically."

Is there any other way to make UI elements hierarchical/reusable besides fragments? For example, I have a SelectLogFileFragment that has some checkboxes/textboxes that I want to be able to use to setup log files from multiple places. If one of those places happens to itself be a fragment, I run into the "can't inflate a layout into a fragment when the layout contains a ".

What are my other options here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using fragments. It is just saying don't put the fragment in the xml. In your FragmentActivity, simply add the fragment to the container in the xml. The xml in your case will be a bunch of containers. That way you can nest to your heart's content!

Comment: Would you use a FrameLayout as the placeholder?

Comment: That generally seems to be the pattern, although it really depends on what you want to do with your layouts. You can really use any ViewGroup you want. Also, if all you have one container in your xml layout, you don't need to use it and just inflate your fragment into android.R.id.content

Answer (score 0):

One solution you could use is a call back design where you would have pass the creation of the nested fragment off to the activity.  This woud allow more flexibilty in your design a help you avoid the nested fragments.  [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) is an example of the design I'm referring to.